# Providing that $f :\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous . prove that Range of $f$ is $\Bbb R$ if $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge|x-y|$ .

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Providing that $f :\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, and suppose

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\ge|x-y|$$

for all real $x$ and $y$. Prove that the **range** of $f$ is $\Bbb R$

This problem is taken from an exercise placed at the end of the Limit chapter and before Differentiation one, so I think we should solve it without using Differentiation and I have no idea how.